# sql create table not working

Tags: mysql, sql, create-table

Trying to migrate this table into the database on my server and I keep getting the error 1146 project.users does not exist.  can anyone see why?

```
 CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `project`.`users` (
      `username` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL ,
      `password` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL ,
      `enabled` BIT(1) NOT NULL ,
      PRIMARY KEY (`username`) )
    ENGINE = InnoDB
    DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = latin1
```

Comment: Does `project` exist?

Comment: Check that you logged in on the right database.

Answer (score 1):

So I've put this in a fiddle slightly modified:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/287ac/1

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (
  `username` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL ,
  `password` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL ,
  `enabled` BIT(1) NOT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`username`) )
ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = latin1
```

And it works as expected.

Try making sure you have "project" database, or change the name project to the one you're migrating to.